# MYSQL find all rows where second row have given values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

my database table looks like:

```
╔════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║ RECIPE_ID ║   NAME    ║
╠════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║        1  ║ Apple     ║
║  2 ║        2  ║ Apple     ║
║  3 ║        2  ║ Orange    ║
║  4 ║        3  ║ Kiwi      ║
║  5 ║        1  ║ Kiwi      ║
║  6 ║        3  ║ Cherry    ║
║  7 ║        3  ║ Banana    ║
╚════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

When i'm querying mysql for `"Apple"` AND `"Orange"`, so i should get the `RECIPE_ID` 2 because `"Apple"` and `"Orange"` have the same `RECIPE_ID`
or second example:

When looking for `"Kiwi"` AND `"Banana"` i should get the `RECIPE_ID` 3

Here is my SQL I have tried

```
SELECT recipe_id, name 
FROM foodtipps.rezepte_zutaten 
WHERE name='Kiwi' AS 'NAME1' AND 
name='Banana AS 'NAME2' GROUP BY recipe_id
```

Hope you understand my problem.
Thank you!

Comment: Show the SQL you have already tried. This is easy so you should already have some SQL.. HINT: the magic is in the WHERE clause

Comment: And provide the table name!

Comment: My try was simple:SELECT `recipe_id`, `name` FROM foodtipps.rezepte_zutaten WHERE `name`='Kiwi' AS 'NAME1' AND `name`='Banana AS 'NAME2' GROUP BY `recipe_id` This doesnt work

Comment: This is a much more natural question to answer (query to write) with a bit of normalization. Consider having a table for ingredients and a separate table for recipes. Then, it's a simple matter of writing some inner-joins.

Comment: @nasukkin Normalization wouldn't help that much, technically this could be part of a normalized schema that has an ingredients table keyed on ingredient_name (not saying keying on such a value is a good idea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be extended to many more ingredients easily:

```
SELECT recipe_id
FROM theTable
WHERE name IN ('Apple', 'Orange')
GROUP BY recipe_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 /* number of ingredients in the list */
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have only two value for search  you can use a inner join

```
select a.recipe_id 
from my_table as a
inner join my_table as b on  a.recipe_id = b.recipe_id
where a.name ='Apple' 
and b.name ='Orange';
```

Comment: there are up to 5 search values, btw. i get sql error in your code

Comment: select RECIPE_ID from table where NAME equals "Apple" intersect select RECIPE_ID from table where NAME equals "Orange"  Will this work ?

Comment: @scaisEdge sorry my bad

Comment: @rUCHit31  do not worry it happens to me too  using different databases

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by scaisEdge **solves the problem you asked**.

It's possible to extend this to support an indefinite number of ingredients, but its a bit messy adding a join to the table each time, hence...

```
 SELECT recipe_id, COUNT(DISTINCT name)
 FROM recipe
 WHERE name in (
     'Apple',
     'Orange',
      ...
 )
 GROUP BY recipe_id
 ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

You might also add a `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name)=xxx` where xxx is your number of ingredients before the ORDER BY.