# mysql multi row query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Not sure if my title is correct, but let me describe what i am working with.

So I have a view consisting of class_id, entity_id and item_id.  Like this:

```
'21781','4243','15787'
'21781','4249','15793'
'21781','4255','15823'
'21782','4243','15787'
'21782','4249','15793'
'21782','4255','15823'
'21782','4285','15526'
'21782','4288','17588'
'21783','4243','15787'
'21783','4249','15793'
'21783','4255','15823'
'21783','4285','15527'
'21783','4288','17588'
'21784','4243','15787'
'21784','4249','15793'
'21784','4255','15823'
'21784','4285','15527'
'21784','4288','15542'
'21785','4243','15877'
'21785','4249','15793'
'21785','4255','15823'
'21785','4285','15527'
'21785','4288','17588'
```

So you will note that class_id = 21781, has three entity/item pairs: '4243','15787', '4249','15793', and '4255','15823'.  I want to find all those classed that have these same entity/item pairs but not any classes that don't have all three of the same entity/item pair. In other words, if the data set was the one about, the desired query would return class_ids 21782,21783,and 21784, but *not* 21785.

I've been looking so much that my eyes are crossed.  Any ideas from the group-mind?

Comment: so you are looking for all the class id's with the same pairs as 21781. Is 21781 a parameter or is there something significant about that ID?

Comment: nothing significant, just the first one i found with the properties i stated.  It could have easily been 21780 or 21001 or something different.  I just need to find the other classes that shatre the same "properties" (entity/item pair)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: thought that was the case but better to check!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL find all rows where second row have given values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775420/mysql-find-all-rows-where-second-row-have-given-values)  Note that instead of `a in (b, c, ....)` you'll have `(a, b) in ((c,d), (e,f), ....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

PS, it looks from your code like your IDs are VARCHAR? Not sure if that was just to present on here but I have gone with it. If they are VARCHAR you should look at making them INTs

```
SET @classid = '21781';
SELECT  c.class_id
FROM    Class c
        LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    Class
                WHERE   class_id = @classid
            ) a
            ON a.entity_id = c.entity_id AND a.item_id = c.item_id
GROUP BY c.class_id
HAVING COUNT(a.class_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Class WHERE class_id = @classid) AND class_id <> @classid
```

Comment: could use `where c.class_id <> @classid` instead of `AND class_id <> @classid` in the having clause

Comment: True - probably more readable. I think it ended up in the having clause as I realised last minute that it shouldn't show the original class_id so was kind of an afterthought!

Comment: Thanks. I've learned that MySQL allows you to do things with GROUP BY that SQL Server doesn't!

Comment: oh dear, no, be truly careful with MySQL's non-standard syntax. it is governed by server settings (that can be changed) and in recent versions the defaults have changed causing potential havoc, stay with standard SQL syntax. look for only_full_group_by see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select c.class_id
from class c join
     class c2
     on c2.entity_id = c.entity_id and 
        c2.item_id = c.item_id and
        c2.class_id = 21781 join
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from class
      where class_id = 21781
     ) x
group by c.class_id, x.cnt
having count(*) = x.cnt;
```